# Realm in android

Tags: android, realm

I want to use two class for database.
here is my source.

```
public class UserInfo extends RealmObject {
    private String user_email;
    private String nick_name;
    private String expected_date;
    private boolean initial_autho;
    private int resultDay;


    public int getResultDay() {
        return resultDay;
    }

    public void setResultDay(int resultDay) {
        this.resultDay = resultDay;
    }

    public String getUser_email() {
        return user_email;
    }

    public void setUser_email(String user_email) {
        this.user_email = user_email;
    }

    public String getNick_name() {
        return nick_name;
    }

    public void setNick_name(String nick_name) {
        this.nick_name = nick_name;
    }

    public String getExpected_date() {
        return expected_date;
    }

    public void setExpected_date(String expected_date) {
        this.expected_date = expected_date;
    }

    public boolean getInitial_autho() {
        return initial_autho;
    }

    public void setInitial_autho(boolean initial_autho) {
        this.initial_autho = initial_autho;
    }

}
```

```
public class Calendar extends Realmobject {

    private long millis;
    private String note; // 노트
    private String mail; // who
    private int image; // image resource

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return millis;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setDate(long time) {
        this.millis = time;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

How do I use these things in Activity?
I don't know exactly and I much appreciate if you guys could tell about that more specifically as much as you can.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using `_`s in the field names instead of camelCase as you normally would in Java?

Comment: Btw, Realm has some [examples that show how to use it](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/c124469621a1b88abdf71bf99885e52138c8a430/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java#L34-L36).

Comment: I mean, I want to manage my two classes in a one activity

Comment: Just call ```Realm.init(this)``` and ```Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration)``` in your activity.